LyX: Create custom inset that does not show up in exported latex code
I would like to create a custom inset to tell the LyX editor things that should not show up in the .tex file that LyX creates. For example a math macro that "teaches" LyX the \overunderset command, which should not show up in the exported .tex file (as it is already included in AMSmath).
(This is somewhat similar to the LyX field in math macros, but I do not want the macro definition to have any effect in LaTeX at all.)
Is there a value for LatexType that does this? LatexType none just leaves the contents unchanged, but does not hide them.
I can almost achieve this using the Note -> Comment environment: LyX picks up on the Macro, but it has no effect for an exported .pdf. However, the superfluous code still shows up in the .tex file within a comment environment, which is just messy.
The Note -> Note environment is the only one I know that does not show up in the .tex file at all, but the content will also be ignored by LyX.
I have tried to copy the definition of Note:Note from the file stdinsets.inc, but even if I change the name, there is no way to insert the custom inset. I can only make "Flex" insets show up, and if I change the definition to Flex, LaTeX will see an undefined control sequence \note, as LatexName has the value note.
Definition of Note:
InsetLayout Note:Note
    LabelString           Note
    LatexType             command
    LatexName             note
    BgColor               notebg
    LabelFont
      Color               note
      Size                Small
    EndFont
    MultiPar              true
    # Not output for XHTML
    AddToToc              note
    IsTocCaption          true
End

This gives no errors, but I have no way to insert it, note-insert Note2 just inserts a regular LyX Note:
InsetLayout Note:Note2
    LabelString           Note2
    LatexType             command
    LatexName             note
    BgColor               notebg
    LabelFont
      Color               note
      Size                Small
    EndFont
    MultiPar              true
    # Not output for XHTML
    AddToToc              note
    IsTocCaption          true
End

This I can insert via flex-insert "Note2", but gives an error when LaTeX finds \note command:
InsetLayout Flex:Note2
    LabelString           Note2
    LatexType             command
    LatexName             note
    BgColor               notebg
    LabelFont
      Color               note
      Size                Small
    EndFont
    MultiPar              true
    # Not output for XHTML
    AddToToc              note
    IsTocCaption          true
End


Try to call your LaTeXName dummy and then Preamble \def\dummy{} EndPreamble I.e. the null macro. Or simply set the LaTeXType to Paragraph.

Thanks for the comment. The first will work just like using Comment: the contents will still show up in the LaTeX code when exported. LatexType  "Paragraph" works only for styles; for layouts only the values command, environment, or none are allowed. I will look into styles to see if I can find a way to make a style do what I want.

What about LatexType None?

LatexType None puts the content in the source code without changing it.

Just to understand: Are you looking for a way to insert content into your LyX document, but you don't want this content to appear in the .tex file generated by LyX?

@tush Exactly. For example, I want to define a math macro \overunderset so LyX will interpret the command in math mode, but I do not want the macro definition to show up in the .tex file LyX generates.

I am not sure you can achieve this in main-text content; I have read the LyX manuals a couple of times and never seen mentions about creating new math macros, so it makes the problem more difficult. I would suggest you to rethink about your document and to take a different syntax highlighting method than the one you are describing here. LyX is powerful, you can create very fine documents with what the software has to offer.

@tush see section 22 in Help->Math.

There is a new feature in LyX 2.4 that is exactly what you want.

It is now possible to define 'empty' math macros, so as to get a nice display for macros not handled natively by LyX. All you have to do is leave the LaTeX part of the macro empty.

This is also documented in section 22.3 of the math manual (in Help->Math)

Sometimes, you may need to use a LaTeX package which defines a math command that is not natively supported in LyX. This is easy enough to do: Just include the package in the preamble and type out the command in math. As with commands defined in the preamble, however, the display in LyX will not be ‘nice’.
As of LyX 2.4, this problem has been solved. Just define a math macro with empty TeX slot! The LyX part will be used for display, but no corresponding LaTeX will be output.

Here is an example LyX file
#LyX 2.4 created this file. For more info see https://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 620
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children no
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding utf8
\fontencoding auto
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_roman_osf false
\font_sans_osf false
\font_typewriter_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\use_microtype false
\use_dash_ligatures true
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\float_placement class
\float_alignment class
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\use_formatted_ref 0
\use_minted 0
\use_lineno 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008080
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\is_math_indent 0
\math_numbering_side default
\quotes_style english
\dynamic_quotes 0
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tablestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\change_bars false
\postpone_fragile_content true
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\docbook_table_output 0
\docbook_mathml_prefix 1
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset FormulaMacro
\newcommand{\overunderset}[3]{}
{\overset{#1}{\underset{#2}{#3}}}
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Formula 
\[
\overunderset 132
\]

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document


This is the LaTeX output (assuming pdfTeX is used)
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\[
\overunderset 132
\]

\end{document}

And the pdf


Perfect. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.
